# Algorithm to find dominant color in CGRect not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm trying to write a method which returns the most frequent color within an area (represented by a CGRect) in a UIView.

This is the code I've developed so far but it doesn't seem to work. The NSLog out lists the color of each pixel and it always displays white (255,255,255) even if i've added a few red streaks.

I'd appreciate if if someone could tell me where the problem is:

```
- (UIColor *) dominantColorInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIColor * dominantColor = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    int bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * rect.size.width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    unsigned int bitmapSize = bytesPerRow * rect.size.height;
    unsigned char pixelData[bitmapSize];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData,
                                                 rect.size.width,
                                                 rect.size.height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent,
                                                 bytesPerRow,
                                                 colorSpace,   
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);


    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -rect.origin.x, -rect.origin.y);
    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    if (pixelData) {
        unsigned long size = sizeof(pixelData)/sizeof(unsigned char);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += bytesPerPixel) {
            UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixelData[0]/255.0 
                                       green:pixelData[1]/255.0 
                                       blue:pixelData[2]/255.0 
                                       alpha:pixelData[3]/255.0];

            if (color) {

                const CGFloat * colors = CGColorGetComponents( color.CGColor);
                CGFloat red = colors[0]*255;
                CGFloat green = colors[1]*255;
                CGFloat blue = colors[2]*255;

                NSLog(@"This Color: %f,%f,%f",red,green,blue);


                NSInteger count = [[dictionary objectForKey:color] integerValue];
                count++;
                [dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] forKey:color];
            }

        }

    }

    int highestFrequency = 0;
    for (id color in dictionary) {
        NSInteger count = [[dictionary objectForKey:color] integerValue];
        //NSInteger count = [object[1] integerValue];
        if (count > highestFrequency) {
            highestFrequency = count;
            dominantColor = color;
        }
    }

    return dominantColor;
}
```

Comment: This returns the color found the most in the image. A mostly white image with a few streaks of red is still mostly white.

Comment: You're right but the NSLog statement outputs the colour of each pixel. Even if red is not the dominant colour, it should still show up in the console output but it doesn't.

Comment: OK, you are saying that the code thinks every pixel is white. Use the debugger and find out why. Is the pixelData showing any values other than 255? If so then check the logic for recalculating the RGB values in your `if (color)` block. BTW - why do you do this? You had the RGB values in the pixelData to start with. Also verify the image data really is 32-bit RGBA and not one of many other possible formats.

Comment: Your `CGContextTranslateCTM()` looks suspicious. What happens if you omit that?

Comment: @MartinR: That's where I think the problem is too! Omitting it makes no difference.

Comment: @rmaddy: As I mentioned in the question, I do not see any value besides 255. The RGB code is correct and the reason i'm doing it twice because i copy pasted the code without realising it was redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You repeatedly read the value of the first pixel in

```
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixelData[0]/255.0 
                                   green:pixelData[1]/255.0 
                                   blue:pixelData[2]/255.0 
                                   alpha:pixelData[3]/255.0];
```

I assume that should be something like

```
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixelData[i]/255.0 
                                   green:pixelData[i+1]/255.0 
                                   blue:pixelData[i+2]/255.0 
                                   alpha:pixelData[i+3]/255.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast, which will return integer values for each component (probably in the range 0-255).

Then you convert those values to floating point, create a UIColor, ask that color for it's R/G/B values, and then convert the values back to integers in the range 0-255. Why go through all that? Just interrogate the byte values of the pixel data.

You then use the UIColor object as a key in a dictionary. That approach will quickly break down for anything other than primary colors. An RGBA
 color has 2^32 possible values, or 4 BILLION possible values. For a photograph, you might get a different color value for every single pixel in the image, and would run out of memory trying to create a dictionary with several million entries in it.

I don't know why you are not logging anything but white pixels, but your design is flawed and you should start over.

Comment: These are all good comments but this makes no attempt to answer the question. This should be posted as a comment.

Comment: I know the implementation is a bit silly but I do intend to use it only for primary colours.

Comment: I think you made some good points here - but RGB has 256^3 = 16777216 values, or 256^4 = 4 Billion for RGBA.

Comment: @MartinR, yes, the OP's code uses RGBA, thus the 4 billion value.

Comment: There is a typo in your answer: 256^ **2**